# Working on Connected sets

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I am trying to prove that if $A, B  \subseteq X$  are subsets with  $\bar{A} \cap \bar{B}  = \emptyset,$ then $A$ and $B$ cannot be separated by a continuous function $ f : X \rightarrow [0, 1]$.

How do I approach this question? Should I start to think that A and B are connected sets? I am a newbie to topology so any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by 'separated by a continuous function'?

Comment: This is false. Suppose that $X=[0,1]$, that $A=\{0\}$, and that $B=\{1\}$. Then just take $f(x)=x$. It separates $A$ and $B$ right?!

Comment: So this statement I am trying to prove is false? How about Urysohn's lemma? Does it apply here?

Comment: Ah, I believe he is seeking an example of such $A,B$ that cannot be seperated..

Comment: How about $[0,{1 \over 2}], ({1 \over 2}, 1]$?

Comment: Is $X$ connected, and any assumption on $A,B$?

Comment: I am so sorry. I fixed the statement. It is supposed to say that the intersection of the closure of A and the closure of B is empty. Sorry everyone!

Comment: Actually, maybe he means separated in the sense that $f(A)=\{1\}$ and $f(B)=\{0\}$.

Comment: @Hugh the example given in the second comment still applies. The subsets $A,B=\{0\},\{1\}$ are closed, so they already contain their closure

Comment: What sort of topology on $X$?

Comment: @yanko the example still applies! Take the identity on $A,B$, then they map exactly to $0,1$ respectively.

Comment: @AndresMejia oh I see

Comment: You need to clarify the question a little, otherwise this is a wild goose chase...

Comment: Urysohn's lemma: If A and B are two subsets of the topological space X, and if there is a continuous function $f : X \rightarrow [0,1]$ such that f(A) = {0} and f(B) = {1}, we say that A and B can be separated by a continuous function.

Comment: $A,B$ are closed, and we require that $X$ is normal for Urysohn's to apply.

Comment: You are looking for a non normal space.

Comment: @AndresMejia I think the assumption is that $\bar{A} \cap \bar{B} = \emptyset$, so A and B are not given to be disjoint.

Comment: If the closures are disjoint then the sets are disjoint!

Comment: Ok calm down. This is difficult stuff.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Do you have any thought on this topic?

Comment: @Hugh Not really. I am not sure if I understood what you are trying to prove.

Comment: I have voted to close this question, it is unclear what OP is asking, and additionally it seems that there are some more fundamental misunderstandings that cannot be remedied. For @Hugh, it would be helpful if you would write verbatim what the question is asking (if you found it somewhere.)

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos James Munkres' book on topology defines a notion as follows: If A and B are two subsets of the topological space X, and if there is a continuous function f : X→ [0,1] such that f(A) = {0} and f(B) = {1}, we say that A and B can be separated by a continuous function. So I think what I am trying to achieve here is maybe because of the give condition of A and B, I cannot find such a continuous f to separate A and B.

Comment: @Hugh: It is difficult. There is a theorem that states that any two disjoint closed sets can be separated by a continuous function **iff** the underlying space is normal. So, the answer to your question is that in general you cannot find such a function. The issue here is that it is not clear what you are really asking.

Comment: @copper.hat I am sorry, copper hat. The statement is just as short as it is, and I cannot get more details about it.

Comment: The Urysohn lemma says that if every pair of disjoint closed sets in X can be separated by disjoint open sets, then each such pair can be separated by a continuous function. So should I focus on proving that I cannot such open disjoint sets?

Comment: As you did not include an important premise you got counter examples.

Comment: Read the comments. If $X$ is normal, then you can separate disjoint sets. So, you need to look for non normal $X$ and then find a pair of closed $A,B$ that cannot be separated.

Comment: Do you actually mean $\overline{A} \cap \overline{B} \neq \emptyset$? That would make it true, not false in general, as it stands now. It has nothing to do with connnectedness BTW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Proving the statement I think the OP means:)

If $A$ and $B$ are separated by a continuous $f: X \to [0,1]$ then $f(x) = 0$ for $x \in A$ just says $A \subseteq f^{-1}[\{0\}]$ and likewise also $B \subseteq f^{-1}[\{1\}]$.

By continuity $f^{-1}[\{0\}]$ and $f^{-1}[\{1\}]$ are closed and disjoint so $\overline{A} \subseteq f^{-1}[\{0\}]$ and $\overline{B} \subseteq f^{-1}[\{1\}]$ are also disjoint, contradiction.

So $\overline{A} \cap \overline{B} \neq \emptyset$ implies that $A$ and $B$ cannot be separated by a continuous function.